# View pager indicator in android studio

Tags: android, maven, android-studio

I want to use view pager indicator library in android studio. As it is available for the maven and not for the gradle project yet so I am adding library folder in android studio and including it in app build.gradle file. Problem arises, when I compiled the project so it wont compile as both the app and library gradle files are using android-support-v4.jar files. I need to know how can I use the library in android studio.

settings.gradle

```
   include ':app'
   include ':library'
   include ':sample'
```

app/build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'android'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':library')
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.+'
}
```

library.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.+'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android-library'

android {
    sourceSets {
        main {
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
        }
    }

    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '19.0.3'
}

dependencies {
    compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
  // compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.+'
   // compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't include the support library by adding a direct dependency to its jar file as you have in your library's **build.gradle** file. If you include it everywhere via the Maven-coordinate-style include, like your commented out line, the build system won't have trouble with duplicates:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.+'
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. If I do the same like you have done in the answer section, I am succeeding in sync gradle files but when I go to run the application it shows the following error.
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
 com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoVersionImpl;

P.S app/build.gradle file is same. I havnt changed it.

Comment: The same as what? If in your app's build file you're also using the `compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.+'` method it should work. Make sure you remove any copies of the jar you've put in your libs folders everywhere, in case it's picking those up automatically.

Comment: Let me show you what I have done yet.
My app gradle file:
`code`
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.+'
    compile project(':library')
}

My library gradle:
dependencies {
    // compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.+'
    // compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
`code`
If I do not include support v4 file in library gradle then it asks for it. I have removed all the v4.jar files in the project.

Comment: I have done Invalidate Caches / Restart > then "Invalidate and restart" but still getting the same error of multiple dex files.

Comment: I dont know why is it not working. After restarting my computer, it is working fine now. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

1. Select "Projects" module in android studio.
2. download and unzip the ViewPagerIndicator-Library.
3. Create the libs folder under root folder and copy paste the library into that folder.
4. go to settings.gradle and add this line:
   `include ':libs:ViewPagerIndicator-Library'`
5. add the `compile project(':libs:ViewPagerIndicator-Library')` in app's build.gradle model
6. Restart the studio and Have Fun ...